# XML: Using wildcard with required attribute of type xs:QName

Tags: xml, xsd, qnames

My XML schema has the rule:

`<xs:attribute name="A" type="xs:QName" use="required"/>`

I want to be able to provide a wildcard to my XML rule file for this tag e.g.

`<Element A="<wildcard_character>" Operation="doStuff">`

Normally the value of the attribute is a regular qualified string name but I'd like to be able to provide a wildcard character as well in some cases.  Is there such a character for the type xs:QName?  I've tried * with no luck.  Alternatively, is there a type which would allow wildcards?

No luck with google so I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A QName is a "qualified name". "*" is not a name of any kind. Sorry.

Comment: I figured as much.  Do you know of another type I could use which allows wildcards?

Comment: There is no such thing as wildcards. They are only characters. You simply need a type that permits that character, like `xs:string`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use **_** (underscore), as in operator *like* in sql ?